# Как вызвать скрипт при прокрутке до определенного div и повторить его только один раз?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, необходимо, чтобы при прокрутке до определенного блока запускалась анимация и после окончания больше не повторялась. На данный момент у меня получилось только сделать так, чтобы она вызывалась сразу при скролле, при этом всякий раз при скролле анимация запускается заново. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно исправить код?

```
function animate(options) {

var start = performance.now();

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    var timeFraction = (time - start) / options.duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    var progress = options.timing(timeFraction);

    options.draw(progress);

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

});
}

window.onscroll = function myRotate() {
var rotate = 120;
var transformOrigin = 'transform-origin';
animate({
    duration: 5000,
    timing: bounceEaseOut,
    draw: function(progress) {
        img_arrow.style.transform = "rotate(" + progress*rotate + "deg)";
        img_arrow.style.transformOrigin = "75% 71%";
    }
});
};

function linear(timeFraction) {
return timeFraction;
}

function bounce(timeFraction) {
for (var a = 0, b = 1, result; 1; a += b, b /= 2) {
    if (timeFraction >= (7 - 4 * a) / 11) {
        return -Math.pow((11 - 6 * a - 11 * timeFraction) / 4, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)
    }
}
}

function quad(progress) {
return Math.pow(progress, 2)
}

function makeEaseOut(timing) {
return function(timeFraction) {
    return 1 - timing(1 - timeFraction);
}
}

var bounceEaseOut = makeEaseOut(bounce);
var quadEasyOut = makeEaseOut(quad);
```

Comment: Объяви флаг, функцию анимирования  обверни в if. Проверяй флаг, запуская if меняй флаг на обратный.